# IPFS dapp hosting

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, ganache, ipfs

I have uploaded the dapp frontend folder along with contracts json files on the IPFS using

```
ipfs add <path>
ipfs name publish <hash>
```

commands. I am running Ganache for in-memory virtual blockchain. ipfs daemon is running but when I open https://ipfs.io/ipfs/(hash) the site is loading not opening unlike when I open localhost:8080/ipfs/(hash).
I checked

```
ipfs swarm peers
```

I have 120 connected peers. What could be the problem?

Comment: What are you using Ganache for? IPFS does not depend on Ethereum.

Comment: Does any error appears on the browser development console?

Comment: Actually, I waited for some time after which the dapp loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using https://terminal.co to host on IPFS. It makes it much easier by linking your GitHub repository and deploying the website. Also, you can add a custom domain if you would like.